# Flutter Project does not work on debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a project which was working fine but after updating Flutter I find a  weird error when I run my app from the Android studio debug button

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 3.3.5.

Because doki_app depends on fluent_ui >=4.3.0 which requires Flutter SDK version  
>=3.7.0, version solving failed.
```

but when I run it from the terminal every thing works fine.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm64, locale en-IR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have two different versions of Flutter namely `3.3.5` and `3.7.10` installed on your computer. This is possible because your IDE has its own setting to know where it should look for Flutter SDK which is what is being used as described by your `current SDK version`

From the terminal when you are running the flutter command it uses your `PATH environment variable` to search for an executable matching your command name.

So my guess is that your `IDE` and `PATH environment variable` points to two different Flutter installations on your computer.

Hence, to solve this you need to either update your `PATH environment variable` to point to the correct version. Ideally you will need to point it to the more latest `3.7.10` if your planning on using `fluent_ui >= 4.3.0`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix my problem using this advice.
i found the Flutter SDK path in Android Studio and the version was lower
for some reasons Flutter upgrade command downloaded the new version in another location

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are have multiple flutter SDK versions installed on your computer.
In terminal you have default Flutter version 3.7.10.
In your Android Studio it seems like you have Flutter version 3.3.5, that's why you get an error:

```
doki_app depends on fluent_ui >=4.3.0 which requires Flutter SDK version  
>=3.7.0, version solving failed.
```

Make sure you have Flutter 3.7.10 selected on your Anroid Studio  as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `pubspec.lock` file in your project and search for `sdks` term, then change both the `dart` and `flutter` versions due to your machine's `dart` and `flutter` versions.

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.19.2 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=3.7.0"
```

An IDE or PC restart will make it better.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

then

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter run
```

if still not works run this command

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```